# casting functions into function pointers in a c programme

Tags: c, casting

I am trying to understand a software for a Tire Pressure Monitoring System but I know little about C language.
In one of the header files there is these kind of definitions :

```
#define TPMS_RESET         gu16AddressToFn = u16fnDALLinkFmw(gu8Derivative, FN_RESET);\
                       ((void(*)(void))(gu16AddressToFn))

/* UINT8 TPMS_READ_VOLTAGE(UINT16 *u16UUMA) */
#define  TPMS_READ_VOLTAGE  ((UINT8(*)(UINT16*))(u16fnDALLinkFmw(gu8Derivative, FN_READ_VOLT)))

/* UINT8 TPMS_COMP_VOLTAGE(UINT8 *u8CompVoltage, *UINT16 u16UUMA) */
#define  TPMS_COMP_VOLTAGE  ((UINT8(*)(UINT8*, UINT16*))(u16fnDALLinkFmw(gu8Derivative, FN_COMP_V)))

/* UINT8 TPMS_READ_TEMPERATURE(UINT16 *u16UUMA) */
#define  TPMS_READ_TEMPERATURE  ((UINT8(*)(UINT16*))(u16fnDALLinkFmw(gu8Derivative, FN_READ_T)))

/* UINT8 TPMS_COMP_TEMPERATURE(UINT8 *u8Temp, UINT16 *u16UUMA) */
#define  TPMS_COMP_TEMPERATURE   ((UINT8(*)(UINT8*, UINT16*))(u16fnDALLinkFmw(gu8Derivative, FN_COMP_T)))

/* UINT8 TPMS_READ_PRESSURE(UINT16 *u16UUMA, UINT8 u8Avg) */
#define  TPMS_READ_PRESSURE    ((UINT8(*)(UINT16*, UINT8))(u16fnDALLinkFmw(gu8Derivative, FN_READ_P)))

/* UINT8 TPMS_COMP_PRESSURE(UINT16 *u16CompPressure, UINT16 *u16UUMA) */
#define  TPMS_COMP_PRESSURE    ((UINT8(*)(UINT16*, UINT16*))(u16fnDALLinkFmw(gu8Derivative, FN_COMP_P)))    

/* UINT8 TPMS_READ_ACCEL_X(UINT16 *u16UUMA, UINT8 u8Avg, UINT8 u8FiltSelect, UINT8 u8DynamicOffset) */
#define  TPMS_READ_ACCEL_X  ((UINT8(*)(UINT16*, UINT8, UINT8, UINT8))(u16fnDALLinkFmw(gu8Derivative, FN_READ_X)))

/* UINT8 TPMS_READ_ACCEL_Z(UINT16 *u16UUMA, UINT8 u8Avg, UINT8 u8FiltSelect, UINT8 u8DynamicOffset) */
#define  TPMS_READ_ACCEL_Z ((UINT8(*)(UINT16*, UINT8, UINT8, UINT8))(u16fnDALLinkFmw(gu8Derivative, FN_READ_Z)))
```

I don´t really understand this trick of casting into other functions. Have you got any idea?

Comment: What is `u16fnDALLinkFmw`? What is `gu8Derivative`?

Comment: This is a perfect example of where using `typedef`'s would lead to much more understandable code.

Answer (score 5):

Function pointer casting is a way to convert non-C firmware memory addresses into valid function declarations in C. This is normally done in embedded systems when you're accessing firmware functions (probably written in non-C languages / assembly) without the firmware's API exposed as a C API.

For example, in your case, the firmware provides a list of addresses to firmware functions in `gu8Derivative` (a *jump-table* in the firmware code). Using `u16fnDALLinkFmw(gu8Derivative, X)` you can get the *jump-address* of function `X` in firmware which is equivalent to a function pointer in C. Now, since the function declaration in firmware is not known directly in C, it is provided as a function pointer cast with an accompanying comment describing the API of the corresponding firmware function.

[This NXP community post](https://community.nxp.com/thread/381866) gives some more details about this exact firmware you're trying to use.

Comment: In "gu16AddressToFn", gu8 stands for global unsigned 8-bit?

Comment: `u16` and `u8` normally stand for `unsigned` 16-bit or 8-bit, but I'm not sure what `g` means here - `global` appears possible, but it's difficult to comment without looking at more code.

Answer (score 0):

The macros you present are all ultimately defined in terms of a function (likely) or perhaps another macro (unlikely), `u16fnDALLinkFmw()`.  I'll suppose it is a function.  You haven't quite understood what is going on here, however: the code in the macros' replacement texts are not casting *that function*; rather, they are casting its *return value*.

What seems to be going on here, therefore, is a variation on dynamic dispatch.  The macros provide for looking up each desired function in a specified table, by offset / id, and since the looked-up functions for different IDs may have different signatures, the macros cast the returned function pointer to the correct-signature function pointer type.

You would use these something like this:

```
uint16_t argument = 1;
uint8_t  result = TPMS_READ_VOLTAGE(&argument);
```